# Non existing Attributes HTML Input Field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input-field

Is it good practice to attach an non existing attribute to an html element in order to use it in jquery. For example

```
<input type="text" valrule="someregexstring" />
```

then simply use jquery to select all elements which contain an attribute called valrule and parse the regex string.

Is this a 'no-go' as far as programming standards and best practices go?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use the prefix `data-<myAttribute>`. It is supported by HTML5, other browsers will ignore it and you can access it easily with jQuery using the `.data()` method.

```
<input  id="myInput" type="text" data-MySuperMassiveAttribute="Awesome"/>
```

and you can retrieve that information like so :

```
var howAmI = $('#myInput').data('MySuperMassiveAttribute');
alert(howAmI); // now everybody knows how awesome you are ;-)
```

Comment: In my case (php). By default the attribute key has been lowercased. And the function data() is key sensitive. So when I entered the key name with camelcase convention I could find it by jquery so I had to lowercase any capital letter in the key.

Answer (score 3):

Use HTML5 data- prefix for new attribute like this:

```
<input type="text" data-valrule="someregexstring" />
```

Its valid HTML 5..

http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/

Comment: and browsers which don't support html5 yet? will they simply ignore the attribute?

Comment: Will just ignore it... The point is that is valid for HTML 5.

Comment: Yes, and you can simply call jquery data() function to grab the corresponding value. 
`<div data-foo="bar"></div>`

`var baz = $('div').data('foo');`

Answer (score 2):

You definitely can. Although HTML5 introduced what's called *data-* attributes, allowing to set non-standard attributes to elements in a standard way.

You simply prefix the attribute names with `data-`

```
<input type="text" data-valrule="someregexstring" />
```

Although, this is introduced in HTML5, you can still use it with documents for HTML4.

---

Using jQuery (1.4.3+), the *data-* attributes can be accessed with [.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/) - or via [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).

Answer (score 0):

I personally wouldn't do that.  Some browsers ignore "non-existing" attributes when parsing HTML, therefore these attributes wouldn't be saved in the browser page DOM.  When jQuery selectors are executed, they may not find this attribute.

If you are guaranteed to run in HTML5-compliant browsers, then you can use HTML5 `data-` prefix for your attributes, e.g.

```
<input type="text" data-valrule="someregexstring" />
```

However this still may not work if you run in older browsers. For example, it turns out that almost half of our clients are using IE7 with no plans to upgrade (moving with the speed of government).

Comment: What do you mean ignore? I had never encountered a problem with "non-existing" attributes... and data-* is valid in HTML <5!

Comment: I did not state that this will definitely happen.  I merely indicated that the behaviour for "non-existing" attributes is not defined for older browsers.

Comment: @gdoron - "data-* is valid in HTML <5". Where did you get that from?

Comment: @Alohci. Well... works well in all modern browsers is valid (for me). I don't care about the spec as long as it works, just like with the `type="javascript` can be removed...

Comment: @gdoron I specifically said "older browsers". Yet you are saying "modern browsers".  Is firefox 3.6 considered "modern" by your standard?  It doesn't support it properly.