# jQuery ajax not getting every div elements

Tags: jquery

I'm parsing an html document with jQuery using $.ajax and I have the following problem, some divs have some uncommon attributes as you can see:
`<div id='img' title='blabla' no='number' src='smthin'>content</div>`
But the problem is that ajax only output:
`<div id='img' title='blalba' src='smthin'>`
The no attribute is skipped, how can I solve it ?

Comment: Perhaps relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9684323/non-existing-attributes-html-input-field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use data- prefix for user-defined attributes in HTML tags. Try usind data-no instead of no attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I have enough info: http://jsfiddle.net/mikevoermans/yEREC/

The fiddle seems to keep the attributes.

Comment: The problem is that the parser don't give me the attributes, if they were here, I could parse it.

Answer (score 0):

try (if possible) to use data attributes 
http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/